# CroppedImage from BitmapImage

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I am trying to display a fixed part of an Image in an `Image` control. The Source is a `BitmapImage` either from the disk or a web resource and is loaded asynchronously.

I tried using `CroppedImage`

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CroppedBitmap x:Key="croppedImage" Source="{Binding Image}" SourceRect="20 46 273 202"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
...
<Image x:Name="TemplateImage" Height="202" Width="273" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="{StaticResource croppedImage}"/>
```

This produces an `XamlParseException` when trying to create the `CroppedBitmap`.
I also tried this in the code behind (C#)

```
new CroppedBitmap(Image, new System.Windows.Int32Rect(20, 46, 273, 202))
```

giving me an `ArgumentException` when loading from a web resource, stating that the value is out of the expected range. I suppose this is due to the Image not yet beeing loaded, thus having no size.

Is there a way to accomplish this (not necessarily with a `CroppedImage`), without having to preload the image?

btw: Giving the `BitmapImage` directly as source to the `Image` control works fine, but of course this does not do the cropping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the Image control you may use a Rectangle with an ImageBrush Fill, and set the Viewbox as needed:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ImageBrush x:Key="croppedImage" ImageSource="{Binding Image}"
                ViewboxUnits="Absolute" Viewbox="20,46,273,202"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
...
<Rectangle Height="202" Width="273" Fill="{StaticResource croppedImage}"/>
```

Comment: Many thanks, this works. Although that made me discover another problem, the images have differing resolutions (dpi) though each having the same PixelSize. Is there a way to control the dpi, when creating the `BitmapImage`? The `DecodePixelHeight` and `DecodePixelWidth` seem to do nothing about it.

Comment: I guess you would have to create a new BitmapSource (or the derived WriteableBitmap) with appropriate DPI values from the original pixel data.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is create a dummy source that is just a blank bitmap:

```
var src = BitmapImage.Create(
                        500, // set to be big enough so it can be cropped
                        500, // set to be big enough so it can be cropped
                        96,
                        96,
                        System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Indexed1,
                        new BitmapPalette(new List<System.Windows.Media.Color> { System.Windows.Media.Colors.Transparent }),
                        new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                        1);
```

Set your Image property that is bound as the source of the CroppedBitmap to this dummy. Then when the actual image loads you just replace this dummy with the real one. The binding system should take care of updating it when you set the `Image` property to the new source.