# Wpf shared image memory

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to optimize the memory usage in my WPF app.
I want to load from the disk an jpg image and show it with its real size.
And then I want to show 5 cropped square section of the original image loaded from the disk.
(No resize is applied on any image).
I want to do all this by loading the original image once and sharing that data among the image controls, in such a way that no memory is wasted and all controls fetch data from the same memory location.

I tried by using a memory stream object but in the end due to some convertions between bitmap and bitmapimage I ended up copying the data.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example showing code that you have tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It will be difficult to help you if we can't reproduce the problem that you are running into.

Comment: Also, you may want to rephrase your question. Background information is helpful, but right now all you have is a list of requirements, and what you don't have is one clear and concise question. You may also want to look at Stackoverflow's article on how to ask good questions here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Use CroppedBitmap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an interesting way to crop an image from a BitmapImage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19599658/4708150) that I think will solve your problem. Doing it this way, you can display all of your images just using a single `BitmapImage`

In your xaml your full resolution image would just be a regular image element, but your cropped images would be a rectangle element using an image brush with a specific viewbox. Just define the rectangle with the height and width of the cropped image that you want, and then the viewbox is defined as "x y width height" (in my example it is "10 20 100 200") and remember that x starts at 0 for left and is positive moving right, and y starts at 0 for the top and is positive moving down.

```xml
    <Image Source="{Binding Image}"></Image>
    <Rectangle Height="200" Width="100">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ViewboxUnits="Absolute" Viewbox="10,20,100,200" ImageSource="{Binding Image}"></ImageBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
```

Note that the binding for the Image and the ImageBrush are the same, so you only need to define `Image` once, and it is used across both elements.